# Searching within HTML elements in RSpec view tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, view

As part of my view specs, I sometimes like to check that the right text is also rendered for a certain element on the page.

Let's say the rendered HTML is -

```
<div class="user-msg">
  <b>Thank You!</b>
</div>
```

I might test in my view specs as -

```
expect(rendered).to match(/Thank You/)
```

However this could incorrectly fail or pass depending on whether there's something else on the page that also says "Thank You".

How do I search within the specific `<div>` in question? If this were a feature test I'd use Capybara to select the node -

```
within(".user-mssg") { expect(page.body).to have_content("Thank You") }
```

How do I find a specific HTML element (e.g. `.user-msg`) and search within it in my View specs?

Thanks!

*Edit*: "Thank you!"

Answer (score 7):

[rspec-html-matchers](https://github.com/kucaahbe/rspec-html-matchers) does just that:

```
<h1>Simple Form</h1>
<form action="/users" method="post">
<p>
  <input type="email" name="user[email]" />
</p>
<p>
  <input type="submit" id="special_submit" />
</p>
</form>
```

spec:

```
expect(rendered).to have_tag('form', :with => { :action => '/users', :method => 'post' }) do
  with_tag "input", :with => { :name => "user[email]", :type => 'email' }
  with_tag "input#special_submit", :count => 1
  without_tag "h1", :text => 'unneeded tag'
  without_tag "p",  :text => /content/i
end
```